# Can we use python 32 bit for Microsoft visual code 64bit?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

Can we use python 32 bit latest version for Microsoft visualCode
64 bit ? Can it work?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, there is no relation between the version of VS Code and Python 3 (32 or 64 bit). VS Code is just a editor. I recommend you use the version of Python same as your CPU architecture (32 or 64 bit).